# Which minifier does Liferay use?

Tags: liferay, minify

Which [minifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) does Liferay use? Any and all versions.

(This is a surprisingly simple question and yet I could not find the answer online)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is not an easy question to answer that I can see.

Comment: Liferay uses the YUI minifier. I'm guessing you're getting the down votes due to poor tag choices.

Comment: @rp. Thanks for the response. If you put it as answer (along with how you know it), I will mark it as correct. (Also, not seeing anything wrong with the tags, but I'm not going to worry about it).

Comment: If you look at `MinifierUtil` you can see it loads up the YUI minifier for CSS at line 52 and JS at line 71.

Comment: @rp. Please promote your comment to answer for upvotes/acceptance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liferay uses two minifiers YUI Minifier for JS and CSS and Google Minifier for JS.

By default, Liferay will the Google minifier for JS and YUI for everything else. If you would like to use the YUI minifier for JS set:

`minifier.javascript.impl=com.liferay.portal.minifier.YahooJavaScriptMinifier`

in your `portlet-ext.properties`.

See the [minifier package](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7879fbf383b5fc2c1c850f65673edfadd365e612/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/minifier) on GitHub.